# Removing Invalid Characters from JSON response in TEIID

Tags: sql, json, teiid

I have a json response generated from invokeHTTP function and then passing it to materialized view. Apparently there is control character embedded in the response. When converting to XMLTABLE I get below error:

```
    at org.teiid.query.xquery.saxon.XQueryEvaluator.evaluateXQuery(XQueryEvaluator.java:147) [teiid-engine-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1]
    at org.teiid.query.processor.relational.XMLTableNode$1.run(XMLTableNode.java:269) [teiid-engine-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1]
    at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DQPWorkContext.runInContext(DQPWorkContext.java:282) [teiid-engine-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1]
    at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:119) [teiid-engine-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1]
    at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$3.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:210) [teiid-engine-9.1.1.jar:9.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: nu.xom.ParsingException: 0x8 is not allowed in XML content
```

Example Response:

```
result
[
   {
      "firstName":"John\b",
      "lastName":"Doe"
   }
]
```

View definition:

```
CREATE VIEW Information (firstName string, lastName String) AS
    SELECT x.firstName, x.lastName 
    FROM (EXEC model.invokeHttp(action => 'GET', endpoint => url ,stream => 'TRUE')) AS f,
    XMLTABLE('/result/result' PASSING JSONTOXML('result',f.result) 
    COLUMNS 
    firstName string PATH 'firstName',
    lastName string PATH 'lastName')x
```

Is there any function in TEIID to remove unwanted/control characters from JSON response or skip/exclude the record that has the invalid character ?

Comment: Did you try to convert it via [JSONToXML](http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/9.3.x/content/reference/JSON_Functions.html#_jsontoxml)?

Comment: Yes. It is failing at JSONTOXML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSONTABLE` directly too, see http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_jsontable.html

Also, see other JSON functions at http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_json-functions.html